# I have 2 repos. And I want to sync some files of them?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have 2 repos. Repo A and Repo B. In repo B, I have some files like file_B1, file_B2, file_B3, I want to copy those to Repo A, and keep them syncing from Repo B.

I am new to Github, and I am using Github for my repo.

What should I do?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I am using C#, I don't know if it can help.

Comment: Does syncing the files have anything to do with C#? Are you using C# to sync the files? Because this is not specified and so it simply looks like the C# and .net tag don't belong.

Comment: Note that when you connect two Git repositories to each other, they share *commits*, not files. Commits *contain* files, but the unit of sharing is the commit. To use Git to send three files, you have to put those three files into commits—one commit will suffice—and then have the *commits* get shared. Note also that every commit saves a full snapshot of *every* file, or more precisely, every file that's in Git's *index*, so unless you're careful, you're going to send *all* your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two repositories are completely independent (ie, do not share any common history), then copying the 3 files from one to the other won't trigger any synchronization:
If one of those file changes in repoA, it will not change in repository B.

The best you could do would be to script and automate the copy from A to B, and in that same script, add, commit and push from repoB.

Comment: So, there is no other way to do it?

Comment: @maxrena If those two repositories are not related in any way, then there is no native Git mechanism which would automagically synchronize just those few files. Scripting it remains a viable alternative, one which can be customize to your specific case.